# Can Universal Link opens directly the target App without showing popup from Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm developing an App and implementing Universal Links (UL) on iOS.

They work correctly if the ULs are used by a third-party App (Mail, Messenger, Telegram and so on): my App opens and points directly to the resource in a fluid way.

However, if the UL is on a web page in Safari and the user uses it: I see a small header at the top of the web page with the App icon and the "Open" button. Clicking on the button works correctly, however I would like this native header not to appear and I would like the UL to take me directly from Safari to my App.

Is it possible to do this?

I am unsure that Deep Links could be better than the Universal Links.

Then I'll have to think about the same functionality for Android, can someone anticipate some useful information on this platform as well?